# IOS 7 unrecognized selector sent to instance issue with button

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a JSON response object that is stored as shown below:

```
ownerEvents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[(NSDictionary *)responseObject objectForKey:@"result"]];
```

ownerEvents stores the JSON below (retrieved via xcode debug window):

```
2014-09-17 01:23:49.311 test123[31919:60b] JSON: {
result =     (
            {
        "end_time" = "4:00AM";
        "event_date" = "09-16-2014";
        "event_id" = 89;
        "event_image" = "http://www.jessetaveras.com/test123/images/event_flyers/event1141091689687507968f3f78ac5f23b2a954bb1dc6d.png";
        "event_price" = 30;
        "event_tickets_total" = 250;
        "event_title" = dfjjsnda;
        "start_time" = "5:00AM";
        "venue_name" = "the shit box";
        weekday = Tuesday;
    }{
        "end_time" = "4:00AM";
        "event_date" = "09-16-2014";
        "event_id" = 89;
        "event_image" = "http://www.jessetaveras.com/test123/images/event_flyers/event1141091689687507968f3f78ac5f23b2a954bb1dc6d.png";
        "event_price" = 30;
        "event_tickets_total" = 250;
        "event_title" = dfjjsnda;
        "start_time" = "5:00AM";
        "venue_name" = "the shit box";
        weekday = Tuesday;
    }
);
}
```

The JSON above is then split into 2 different cells in a table view

I need to send the data of an individual cell to another view controller. Inside the function that is supposed to send the data to the other view controller I have this code:

within the cell class I have:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *editButtonPressed;
```

within CellForRowAtIndexPath (which is in a UIViewController) I have:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"OwnerCell";

TDOwnerViewCell *historyCell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
historyCell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
//NSLog(@"THIS IS current Cell %@", [ownerEvents  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

[historyCell configOwnerEventCell:[ownerEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

[historyCell.editButtonPressed addTarget:self action:@selector(editButtonPressed)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
historyCell.editButtonPressed.tag = indexPath.row;
if(historyCell == nil)
{
historyCell = [[TDOwnerViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"OwnerCell"];
}
return historyCell;    
}
```

This is the method being called when the button is pressed:

```
- (void)editButtonPressed:(UIButton *) button{
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];

TDEventEditViewController * vc3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"eventEditView"];

[historyCell configOwnerEventCell:[ownerEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSInteger index = button.tag;

NSArray *eventsJSONData = [ownerEvents objectAtIndex:index];
ownerEvents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[(NSDictionary *)responseObject objectForKey:@"result"]];

vc3.detailDic = eventsJSONData[index];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
-[TDOwnerViewCell editButtonPressed:]: unrecognized        selector sent to instance 0xca00000
2014-09-17 01:46:21.884 test123[31919:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',  reason: '-[TDOwnerViewCell editButtonPressed:]: unrecognized  selector sent to instance 0xca00000'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x034391e4   __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x031b88e5  objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x034d6243 - [NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0342950b  ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x034290ee  _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x031ca880 - [NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
6   UIKit                               0x01e7a3b9 - [UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
7   UIKit                               0x01e7a345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
8   UIKit                               0x01f7bbd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
9   UIKit                               0x01f7bfc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
10  UIKit                               0x01f7b243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
11  UIKit                               0x022102e3 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7166
12  UIKit                               0x01eb9a5a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
13  UIKit                               0x01eba971 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1021
14  UIKit                               0x01e8c5f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
15  UIKit                               0x01e76353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
16  CoreFoundation                      0x033c277f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
17  CoreFoundation                      0x033c210b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
18  CoreFoundation                      0x033df1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
19  CoreFoundation                      0x033de9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
20  CoreFoundation                      0x033de7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
21  GraphicsServices                    0x04c475ee GSEventRunModal + 192
22  GraphicsServices                    0x04c4742b GSEventRun + 104
23  UIKit                               0x01e78f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
24  test123                               0x000e3f9d main + 141
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x039b6701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of  type NSException
(lldb)
```

Please help, I never seem to figure these errors out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint to your project. That way when it crashes it will take you to the line of code causing the crash.

Comment: You're calling editButtonPressed on a cell and the method isn't there.

Comment: DO you have UITabelView in TDEventEditViewController?

Comment: Try This : Replace vc3.detailDic = eventsJSONData[index]; with vc3.detailDic = eventsJSONData;

Comment: Have you mapped the method editButtonPressed with respective custom tableviewcell if you created there.

Comment: Have a look at your `TDOwnerViewCell` class - you should have a method signature something like `-(IBAction) editButtonPressed:(id)sender` but you don't. It could be something as simple as an uppercase/lowercase letter difference.

Comment: I don't have it set as an action, I have it set as a property in TDOwnerViewCell and I use it as such in TDOwnerViewController. How can I change my code so that it runs the method when pressed? when I change it to a IBAction I get errors because I am trying to use it as a property. I simply trying to send the data that is within 1 of those cells to another view controller (TDEventEditViewController).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

editButtonPressed method might be connected with different method in your storyboard just go to your storyboard and check the connection of the button with the method

Comment: The button is set as a property within the cell class. The function that is used when the button is pressed is in the table view controller's class. This is the code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath: TDOwnerViewCell *historyCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
[historyCell configOwnerEventCell:[ownerEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];            [historyCell.editButtonPressed addTarget:self action:@selector(editButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    historyCell.editButtonPressed.tag = indexPath.row;

Comment: so there is a method called editbuttonPressed so there might be the problem

Comment: have you connected the edit button of your cell from storyboard to TDOwnerViewCell.h

Comment: i guess you have to put a colon at the end of editButtonPressed like @selector(editButtonPressed:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61410/discussion-between-user3007683-and-xphobia).

Answer (score 0):

Your calling this editButtonPressed method which is not connected or present in your logic.

```
-[TDOwnerViewCell editButtonPressed:]: unrecognized        selector sent to instance 0xca00000
2014-09-17 01:46:21.884 test123[31919:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException',  reason: '-[TDOwnerViewCell editButtonPressed:]: unrecognized      selector sent to instance 0xca00000'
```

So could u share your method used for passing data between your VC's.

Update :- 
Firstly, change flow in cellForRowAtIndexPath method as below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"OwnerCell";

  TDOwnerViewCell *historyCell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];

  //You need to check if historyCell is nil or not firstly then move on to your further populating logic.
  if(historyCell == nil)
  {
      historyCell = [[TDOwnerViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"OwnerCell"];
  }

  historyCell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

  [historyCell configOwnerEventCell:[ownerEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

  [historyCell.editButtonPressed addTarget:self action:@selector(editButtonPressed)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  historyCell.editButtonPressed.tag = indexPath.row;

  return historyCell;    
}
```

In your case, issue might be that as u were checking for historyCell is nil or not at end then as in case it was nil then a new history cell was returned.

So try out this and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score -1):

I would set a break point and step through each bit, make sure everything is initialised with what you think  it is.

For instance, does this actually get populated?

```
NSArray *eventsJSONData = [ownerEvents  objectAtIndex:index];
```

Again, does this actually get populated?

```
vc3.detailDic = eventsJSONData[index];
```

Comment: The error is related to a missing method on an instance of `TDOwnerViewCell` - it is nothing to do with the JSON data or a mutable array

Comment: @Paulw11 I have also doubt that SO has doing incorrect parsing of JSON data

Comment: The stack trace clearly states `-[TDOwnerViewCell editButtonPressed:]: unrecognized  selector sent to instance 0xca00000`.  The error is not in the shown code. It is likely resulting from an event handler on a button in a storyboard or nib

Comment: @Paulw11 For the stack trace and code given here only, we cannot figure out that what code is causing problem. It might be code before parsing . You are right that stack trace is giving different error other than we are disussing here. But it is for only SO's concern that his parsing may be wrong

Comment: No, the stack trace and question title are unequivocal - It is a missing method on the cell class

Comment: I see that I may have made a mistake thinking that the issue was with the JSON do you have any suggestions regarding what I should change the title of the question to?

Comment: I cant believe I got a -1 for offering solid debug advice.  It does not matter how good you are, everyone assumes stuff that catches them out!

Comment: You can offer debug advice in a comment.  This doesn't answer the question